# Printing directly from a ti nspire

Tags: printing, calculator, ti-nspire

I got the new ti nspire cx.
I want to print graphs directly from my calculator.
The idea I got to be able to do this was by saving the file to a folder, and the printer automatically checks for files in the folder and prints and deletes them. What would be the best way to make the printer check for this without having a computer involved.

Comment: This calculator does not support WLAN to be able send any files to a shared folder nor can you directly connect a printer to it, so you'd have to connect it to a computer to transfer the graphs. An alternative would be to use the TI-Nspire Software to generate the graps directly on the computer.

Comment: you can use the software on the computer to do it, so is there maybe a way to use the api of that and make a program for the printer? or maybe making a program in C that can be read by ndless to print it.

Comment: You want to modify the TI-Nspire Software to be able to send the graphs via PC to the printer? This is closed source software, you'd have to contact TI to do it for you.

Comment: no the point is that i don't want a computer involved. 
Ndless is the same for the ti nspire as a jailbreak is for the iphone.
For the ti nspire you can write programs in C.
So if would it be able to write a program in C that connects to the printer and can tell the printer to print a file?

Comment: What if a raspberry pi would be connected to the calculator. And which checks for a file in a specific folder, when it finds a file it sends it to a printer and deletes it from the folder.

Comment: The calculator does not have a driver to communicate with the printer, so you would have to write it yourself. Passing the graph to a raspberry pi should be easier. Unfortunately I've never programmed on the calculator, maybe you could ask on this forum: https://www.omnimaga.org/ti-calculator-programming-and-support/